# Integer value is lost in web service call

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx, int

I have an application that makes a web service call to get the URL of an MSI depending on whether the user's computer is 32bit or 64bit.

The call GetURLByOS takes 2 methods (1. string AuthenticationInfo , 2. int osBit). As I'm debugging, I can see the authentication info. The osBit's value is 8 (for 64bit) when calling into the web service. But its value is lost (0) when actually in the web service.

Can someone help me figure out why the integer value is lost?

Update:
I'm attaching to the process. In the client, I see value 8 being passed in. In the web service call, I see 0.
This is a SOAP web service call.
Here's the WSDL code on the client:

```
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://mydomain.com/product/1.0/GetURLByOs", RequestNamespace = "http://mydomain.com/product/1.0", ResponseNamespace = "http://mydomain/product/1.0", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
        public string GetURLByOs(string eTicket, int OsBitType)
        {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("GetURLByOs", new object[] {
                        eTicket, OsBitType});
            return ((string)(results[0]));
        }
```

Here's the actual web service:

```
    [WebMethod]
        public string GetURLByOs(string eTicket, int osBitType)
        {
            return MyFacade.GetUrl(eTicket, osBitType);
        }
```

BTW, when I change the parameter to type string, it gets passed properly (value "8"). It's only when I pass it as an integer that the value is zeroed out.

Comment: do you have an outdated binding/proxy on the client by chance?

Comment: Are you using WCF? And when you say the value is "lost", do you mean that when you attach a debugger to your web service and put your argument in a watch, it shows a value of 0?

Comment: Sorry, but this is nearly impossible to figure out without something else to go on (code, WSDL, etc)...

Comment: Never trust the debugger! Always use logging to see what really is being sent and received.

Comment: Use Fiddler or Wireshark to see what is *actually* being sent.

Comment: @UweKeim and Inuyasha, why is the debugger not reliable in this scenario? Do you have a reference to an article which outlines why the debugger does not yield an adequate answer?

Comment: From time to time I had cases where the debugger is not accurate. Maybe outdated PDB files or the like.

Comment: @KileyNaro, because once inside the debugger, you aren't looking at what was actually sent on the wire at that point.  WCF has already done mysterious things to interpret whatever was sent, and it is that interpretation we want to rule out as a source of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. On the (client) WSDL code, the parameter is OsBitType. But on the actual web service, the parameter is osBitType. After changing the web service parameter to OsBitType, it's working fine.

Strange thing is, this doesn't occur if the parameter is a string.

Answer (score 1):

For my situation, after update reference of web service, it's working fine.